# How to change the java code from GCM functionality to FCM functionality

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
public class GcmIntentService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    public GcmIntentService() {
        // super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        if (!extras.isEmpty() && GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(intent.getExtras());
        }

        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```

Initially I have built a file in GCM without any error and attach it to the firebase, but when I run it in the phone it does not work, so how do I change my java code from GCM to FCM so that it works properly and work as per the firebase.

Comment: if you had googled this you would have found the official gcm->fcm migration guide

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) regarding the migration from GCM to modern FCM.

The flow is as follows:

1. Import your GCM project as a Firebase project
2. Switch to FCM in the app-level build.gradle

   ```
   compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0"
   ```
3. Remove the permissions required by GCM
4. Remove the receiver from the app manifest
5. Migrate your listener service
6. Update the Android Manifest
7. Update your InstanceIDListenerService
8. Remove registration
9. Migrate your GcmListenerService
10. Update the Android Manifest
11. Update your GcmListenerService
12. Update the usage of GcmPubSub
13. Update server endpoints